# How can I make a network for file sharing on windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I'm trying to transfer files between my laptop which uses Wifi and my PC which uses Ethernet cable. I set an IP for each of them. When I press win+R and type the ip, I receive a message that requires a username and a password. Neither one of them has a password. I used to do that in windows xp and everything works after setting up the IP's. What I'm missing in windows 10?

[image]

Comment: Does the laptop have an Ethernet port available? Does the PC have built in wi-fi (might have been disabled)? Are you connecting via a router?

Comment: Does the laptop have an Ethernet port available? Yes but I'm connected to the router using wifi. Does the PC have built in wi-fi? No. Are you connecting via a router? Yes.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Thank you for trying to collect info and answer :)

Comment: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-share-files-and-printers-without-homegroup-windows-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the tested steps below. Check through all, although some settings may already be in place:

When connecting machines, Home Group is gone (security concerns), SMBv1 is gone, and Network Browsing at the Workstation level is unreliable (gone in completely new machines).

The following instructions enable folder sharing between two Windows 10 Machines

1. Make sure Network Discovery and File / Print Sharing are enabled on both computers
2. Make sure password protected sharing is enabled both computers.
3. If you wish to share by computer name instead of IP address, put an entry in the HOSTS file of the computer you are connecting from with the name and IP address of the main computer.
4. Make sure both computers are in the same WORKGROUP and make sure Wireless connections are Private, not Public.
5. This next step depends on computer user names and passwords. If both computers use the same username and password, you can skip this step, restart both and test.

If the user names are different, do the following. Make a username on Main that is a user name and password of the computer you are connecting from. Use this for permissions on the folders on Main you wish to share. It is normally quite difficult to share USER folders because Home Group was removed. Use a neutral folder for sharing.

Again after all the above changes restart and test.

On the computer you are connecting from, open a command prompt and type:
NET USE X: \nameofothercomputer\folder
Press enter and then authenticate with the user name and password credentials.